# Regex for limited numbers, unlimited middle dashes?

Tags: javascript, regex

A user can fill a phone number. ( only digits and dashes , dashes are not mandatory)

He can have as much (*middle*) dashes (`-`) but the total count of digits *must* be 10.

[**I've managed**](http://regexr.com?35f87) writing a regex using positive lookahead of `"-"` in numbers :

`^(?=.*\-)[0-9\-]+$`

But I have 2 problems with that :

- the dash  ( in my regex) can be also in the beginning and at the end and that's **not valid**.
- I haven't succeed applying the 10 digits restrictions.

p.s. examples of **valid** examples :

`050-6783828`
`050-678-38-28`
`0506783828`

**not** valid :

`-0506783826`
`0506783826-`
`050678--3826`

*p.s.2 please notice this question is tagged as regex. I'm not looking for js (non-regex) solutions.*

Comment: My RegExp approach would be to simply .replace(/-/g, "")

Comment: @AlexK. yup. but sometimes you want to have more knowledge  on a certain topic...(rgx)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
^\d(?:-?\d){9}$
```

- Start with a digit.
- 9 times: optional dash and another digit.

Working example: http://rubular.com/r/CrgTOrXC8E

Comment: For me , the most annoying part is that I was expecting a positive lookahead , and didn't find it in your working example......which makes me feel really stupid.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint `:)` Looakeads are *very* common in these patterns though - if you'd add another requirement, that would probably need a lookahead.

Answer (score 2):

```
^[0-9](-?[0-9]){8}-?[0-9]$
```

A digit at the begin and end, 8 groups of optional dash and digit, plus optional dash before last digit

Only one dash is allowed between eatch neighbouring digits.

```
var pat = new RegExp('^[0-9](-?[0-9]){8}-?[0-9]$')
// correct
console.log(pat.test('0506783828'))
console.log(pat.test('0-5-0-6-7-8-3-8-2-8'))
// incorrect
console.log(pat.test('0506783828-'))
console.log(pat.test('-0506783828'))
console.log(pat.test('05--06783828'))
```